# How to find depth of nodes in a nested json file?

Tags: json

I found many solutions to find depth of nodes in a nested json file. but it throws me an error "maximum recursion depth exceeded " 
when it set maximum recursion limit, it says "process exceeded with some error code" 
As a part of my problem, I also need to find out key names of each node in the json file.

example json :

```js
"attachments": {
            "data": [
               {
                  "media": {
                     "image": {
                        "height": 400,
                        "src": "https://scontent.xx.fbcdn.net/v/t1.0-1/10250217_10152130974757825_8645405213175562082_n.jpg?oh=904c1785fc974a3208f1d18ac07d59f3&oe=57CED94D",
                        "width": 400
                     }
                  },
                  "target": {
                     "id": "74286767824",
                     "url": "https://www.facebook.com/LAInternationalAirport/"
                  },
                  "title": "Los Angeles International Airport (LAX)",
                  "type": "map",
                  "url": "https://www.facebook.com/LAInternationalAirport/"
               }
            ]
         }
```

the output should be:

nodes:
[data [media [image[height,width,src]], target[id,url], title, type, url]]

depth: 4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function geth(obj) {
  var depth = 0;
  var k = Object.keys(obj);
  console.log(k);
  for (var i in k) {
      var tmpDepth = geth(obj[k[i]]);
      if (tmpDepth > depth) {
          depth = tmpDepth
      }
  }
  return 1 + depth;
}
```

Comment: this will recursively calculate the depth of json tree

Comment: As it uses recursion, it fails for my object which was very large and nested. Can there be an iterative approach for this ? It will of great help.

Comment: This won't work if the object contains even a single string value. It will result in infinite recursion.

Answer (score 1):

If anyone else came here and found that the accepted answer does not work because Object.keys() for a string returns an array of each character of string and thus for either large objects or objects with large strings it just fails.
Here is something that works ->

```
function getDepth(obj){
    if(!obj || obj.length===0 || typeof(obj)!=="object") return 0;
    const keys = Object.keys(obj);
    let depth = 0;
    keys.forEach(key=>{
        let tmpDepth = getDepth(obj[key]);
        if(tmpDepth>depth){
            depth = tmpDepth;
        }
    })
    return depth+1;
}
```

Exmaple - https://jsfiddle.net/95g3ebp7/

Answer (score 1):

Try the following function:

```
 const getDepth = (
  // eslint-disable-next-line @typescript-eslint/no-explicit-any
  obj: Record<string, any>,
  tempDepth?: number
): number => {
  let depth = tempDepth ? tempDepth : 0;
  if (obj !== null) {
    depth++;
    if (typeof obj === 'object' && !Array.isArray(obj)) {
      const keys = Object.keys(obj);
      if (keys.length > 0)
        depth = Math.max(
          ...keys.map((key) => {
            return getDepth(obj[key], depth);
          })
        );
    } else if (Array.isArray(obj)) {
      if (obj.length > 0)
        depth = Math.max(
          ...obj.map((item) => {
            return getDepth(item, depth);
          })
        );
    }
  }
  return depth;
};
```

If you try this, I believe you have to get `7`.

```
  console.log(getDepth({
    a: {
      b: { a: [{ a: { a: [] } }] }
    }
  }));
```